# getDrawingCache always returns null even though I did everything people recommend on stackoverflow

Tags: android, bitmap, compression

I feel like I have tried literally everything. One last thing comes to mind: do I need root to do getDrawingCache ? I think I shouldn't as this has worked for me when I was playing with it and tried it in a different activity in onClick (even though it saved only the button background).
GraphView is my class painting a graph into the Canvas. I haven't forgotten to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I have tried to use just bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut); without try and catch, it gives the null exception.

Here's the code:

```
        GraphView graphView = new GraphView(this, y, "Dive Planner", horlabels, verlabels, GraphView.LINE, x, Pspotreba, pocetBodu, varovani);
    setContentView(graphView);




        graphView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        graphView.layout(0, 0, graphView.getMeasuredWidth(), graphView.getMeasuredHeight());

        graphView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        graphView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm=Bitmap.createBitmap(graphView.getDrawingCache(true));
        //I have also tried Bitmap bm=graphView.getDrawingCache(true); and all the combinations (using/not using the code above)




        FileOutputStream fOut = null;

        try {   
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "DivePlanner" + File.separator);
                if(!f.exists()) f.mkdirs();
                File dive = new File(f, "Dive.png");

                fOut = new FileOutputStream(dive);
           }
        catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }


        try {
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ponor uložen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
        catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

I am sorry for posting similar question (I have already posted something like this before, but the question remains unaswered, maybe I didn't explain it enough or something, so here's a new try). This is the last thing that I need to finish in my bachelor's thesis. I need to have it ready by the next Tuesday. Everything else works just fine in my code except for this. Thanks in advance, if you can help.